# Manually trigger after_commit on Sequel Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, sequel

Is there a way to force the `DB.transaction` to finish, the `db.after_commit` hook, since is not been triggered in my specs, for some reason the transaction remains active.

ruby class

```
class Album < Sequel::Model
  def after_save
    super
    db.after_commit{ FooWorker.perform_async({ id: id }) }
  end
end
```

rspec

```
describe Album do
  subject{ Album.new() }

  it 'executes the worker' do
    expect(FooWorker).to receive(:perform_async).once
    subject.save
  end
end
```

This spec is broken because the worker is never executed. If I remove the `db.after_commit` the spec passes but then the worker sometimes doesn't find the given `id`.

sequel (4.41.0),
rspec (3.7.0),
ruby (2.3.1p112)

Comment: dont you just need to run `subject.save ` on the line before your expect?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I tried that didn't worked, as far as my knowledge goes the `expect(FooWorker).to receive(:perform_async).once` should be written at the top and then execute the code that should be the one that triggers that expectation. the reason is that is very similar to the `allow(...).to receive(...){...}`, the only difference is that the last one doesn't break the spec if the block is not executed.

Comment: @zetecu can I ask what FooWorker is supposed to do? Also, not sure why you need to test if callbacks are executed. Shouldn't they be already trusted to work as expected by the code which defines them? https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/9cdb740c48b8fdb7407ca1961377d86ddbf523ae/spec/model/hooks_spec.rb

Comment: @lacostenycoder the FooWorker is a sidekiq worker that for a given params {id: id, ...} will process the object, also you are correct I should trust that the callbacks will do the job, the problem here is that if I replace the content of the `db.after_commit{ }` to something else that something else is not been executed on the testing env, and so far I haven't been able to "trigger" that callback.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find the reason why the `after_commit` doesn't finish the transaction. In any case I solved the issue by overriding it (Note the `before` block).

```
describe Album do
  subject{ Album.new() }

  before{ allow(DB).to receive(:after_commit){ |&block| block.call } }

  it 'executes the worker' do
    expect(FooWorker).to receive(:perform_async).once
    subject.save
  end
end
```

Not the ideal solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your tests using `DatabaseCleaner`? If so, you should
check the claening strategy you have configured. If you are using the `:transaction` strategy, it might be that you test runs in a transaction that never gets committed thus your code does not get executed. Try to change the strategy to `:truncation` and it should work.

You can even specify the DB cleaning strategy on a per test basis.

PS. I would also add that rather that expecting a call to `perform_async` you should check that the correct job gets enqueued.